# cambiar el home predeterminado laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

alguien sabe como cambiar el`welcome.balde.php` que tiene por predeterminado laravel y cambiarlo por `home.blade.php`.

Intenté configurandolo en el reoutes.php pero aun me sigue saliendo el welcome, ¿toca hacer una configuración para se ejecute?

```
<?php
  Route::get('/', function(){
    //return View::make('home');
    return '55';
  });
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas?

Comment: @Shaz lavarel 5.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En Laravel 5.4 las rutas del "frontend" se encuentran normalmente en routes/web.php, ahí es donde debes hacer la modificación:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('home');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing

Comment: Muchas gracias, disculpa mi ignorancia, no vi esa carpeta

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando laravel 5.4 prueba usando

```
return view('home');
```

Comment: hola, nada, aun me sigue saliendo el welcome :S